# How exactly do you solve the ODE : $\dot x = -\sqrt{|x|}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do you deal with $ \dot x = -\sqrt{|x|}$

The square root is irksome and the absolute value inside raises serious eyebrows. The function is continuous but has sort of a nondifferentiable point at zero. No one knows how to visualize this function.

Proceeding as usual is a deadend:

$\dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{|x|}} = -dt$

What to do?

Comment: "No one knows how to visualize this function." Not sure what you mean here. "Proceeding as usual is a deadend" Well, not quite, since a primitive of $1/\sqrt{|x|}$ is $2\cdot\mathrm{sgn}(x)\cdot\sqrt{|x|}$, hence one can readily find the unique solution passing by each $x(0)\ne0$. The case $x(0)=0$ is more interesting since then, the uniqueness of the solutions fails.

Comment: Observe that if $x(t)$ solves the equation than $-x(-t)$ also solves it. Hence you can consider the case $x\geq 0$ alone.

Comment: Concerning "how to visualize" your equation, have you considered a slope field? They're quite helpful for any $\dot x=f(t,x)$ given that $f$ is sufficiently "nice".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For $x>0$, 
\begin{align*}
  \frac{dx}{dt} &=-\sqrt{x} \\
  \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}} &=-dt \\
  2\sqrt{x} &= a-t  \\
  x &= \left( \frac{a-t}{2} \right)^{2} \:,\quad t<a
\end{align*}

For $x<0$, 
\begin{align*}
  \frac{dx}{dt} &=-\sqrt{-x} \\
  \frac{dx}{\sqrt{-x}} &=-dt \\
  -2\sqrt{-x} &= b-t \\
  2\sqrt{-x} &= t-b \\
  x &= -\left( \frac{t-b}{2} \right)^{2} \:,\quad t>b
\end{align*}

**In general** the solution space can be connected ($a=b$) or disconected semi-parabolae ($a\neq b$) subject to different initial/boundary conditions.

**Edit :** 
Thanks to all the commenters, continuity can be achieved by setting $x(t)=0, \forall t\in [a,b]$ provided $a\leq b$. In case of $a=-1,b=2$, we have

[image]

Comment: This is not correct. You square negative numbers and get "nonexistant solutions"

Comment: @Artem Thanks for your remind, edited

Comment: +1 but I would presume that when the equation begins $x'=-\sqrt{|x|}$, that this means that $x'(0)$ exists (not just as one-sided derivatives.) So I would presume that the equation implies it's looking for the solutions with $a=b$.

Comment: The answer is still incorrect (not full). And I am a little surprised that an incorrect answer gets two upvotes whereas there is a perfectly fine answer on the page.

Comment: Also it would be more conventional to use $t$ as the horizontal variable and $x$ as the vertical variable, since $t$ is used as the independent variable here.

Comment: @Artem, Ha Ha, the $y$-axis represents $t$.

Comment: Yes, I figured this :) But please read my edited comment above.

Comment: @alex.jordan For every $t_-\leqslant t_+$, the function defined as $x(t)=\frac14(t-t_-)^2$ for $t<t_-$, $x(t)=0$ for $t_-\leqslant t\leqslant t_+$, $x(t)=-\frac14(t-t_+)^2$, solves the differential equation (in particular, $x$ is differentiable everywhere).

Comment: Yes the figure is atrocious... :-)

Comment: Just try keep using $x$-axis to represent $x$.

Comment: @NgChungTak How did you know that $t$ is supposed to be less than $a$ in the first case and greater than $b$ in the second

Comment: @Lookbehindyou, Because of $2\sqrt{|x|}\geq 0$ that I missed initially.

Comment: @NgChungTak Sorry I don't quite understand. Let $t = a+1$, plug this into $(\frac{a-t}{2})^2$, then outcomes $x = 1/4$ at $t = a+1$. What is wrong with this solution?

Comment: @Lookbehindyou behindyou Don't forget the derivatives

Comment: To elaborate on @Did's comment, you can define the function to be $0$ on any closed interval $[a,b]$, and that is a solution on that interval. It's a solution that is missed from the process in this answer, because this answer's first step is to divide by $\sqrt{x}$ which assumes that $\sqrt{x}$ is nonzero. Once you define the function to be $0$ on $[a,b]$ (possibly with $a=b$) then at the tips $a$ and $b$ you can extend as semiparabolas, using partial solutions from the separable solving process detailed in this answer.

Comment: *Much* better figure... :-)

Answer (score 4):

use the separation of variable to get the solution. all solution are decreasing. solution starting at a positive value at time $0$ eventually becomes zero in finite time.

the differential equation $$\dot x = -\sqrt{|x|}, x(0) = x_0$$ has the solution 
$$x = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} 
\left(\sqrt{x_0} - \frac t2\right)^2 & \text{ if $x_0 > 0, t \le 2\sqrt x_0$ }\\
0 &\text{ if $x_0 > 0$ } \\
 -\left(\sqrt{-x_0}- \frac t2\right)^2 & \text{ if $x_0 < 0, t \ge -2\sqrt{-x_0}$ }
\end{array}
\right.$$

Comment: why is there a $t \leq 2 \sqrt{x_o}$ condition? I thought you only had condition on $t$ if the solution blows up afterwards. here our solution do not blow up if $t \geq 2 \sqrt{x_o}$

Comment: @Lookbehindyou, the solution starting at $x_0>0$ at time $t = 0$ decreases to zero at time $t = 2 \sqrt{x_0}$ and joins the steady state $x = 0.$  there is nonuniqueness for the initial value $x = 0.$ you could continue the solution nonuniquley for $t \ge 0$ by following the zero value and then going into negative value for $x$ in many ways.